# Escaping special characters in to_tsquery

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

How do you espace special characters in string passed to `to_tsquery`? For instance, this kind of query:

```
select to_tsquery('AT&T');
```

Produces:

```
NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored

 to_tsquery 
------------

(1 row)
```

Edit: I also noticed that there is the same issue in `to_tsvector`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple solution is to create the tsquery as follows:

```
select $$'AT&T'$$::tsquery;
```

You can make more complex queries:

```
select $$'AT&T' & Phone | '|Bang!'$$::tsquery;
```

See the text search [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-textsearch.html) for more.

Comment: Caution: this won't apply the various dictionary transformations performed by `to_tsquery`,  such as stemming, synonym grouping and stopword removal. This may mean that some queries will never find a match.

Answer (score 10):

I found this comment very useful that uses the `plainto_tsquery('AT&T)` function https://stackoverflow.com/a/16020565/350195

Comment: Is there anyway to support partial matching e.g. adding :* onto the end with this?

Comment: @ColinD I'm sorry, but have you found a way to do this?

Comment: I left the project that I was using for this but I don't remember achieving the solution, my final query was like this         `query = "SELECT o.ortholog_id, g.gene_id, g.species_id, g.description, g.symbol FROM search_index s JOIN orthologs o on o.ortholog_id = s.ortholog_id JOIN genes g on o.gene_id = g.gene_id WHERE s.document @@ to_tsquery('english', ?search) ORDER BY ts_rank(s.document, to_tsquery('english', ?search)) DESC, o.ortholog_id LIMIT 300";` and if I remember correctly the user could manually add * to the query

Answer (score 2):

If you want 'AT&T' to be treated as a search word, you're going to need some customised components, because the default parser splits it as two words:

```
steve@steve@[local] =# select * from ts_parse('default', 'AT&T');
 tokid | token 
-------+-------
     1 | AT
    12 | &
     1 | T
(3 rows)
steve@steve@[local] =# select * from ts_debug('simple', 'AT&T');
   alias   |   description   | token | dictionaries | dictionary | lexemes 
-----------+-----------------+-------+--------------+------------+---------
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | AT    | {simple}     | simple     | {at}
 blank     | Space symbols   | &     | {}           |            | 
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | T     | {simple}     | simple     | {t}
(3 rows)
```

As you can see from [the documentation for CREATE TEXT PARSER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtsparser.html) this is not very trivial, as the parser appears to need to be a C function.

You might find this post of someone getting "underscore_word" to be recognised as a single token useful: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Configuring-Text-Search-parser-td2846645.html

Comment: second link is dead