# PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error in tsquery

Tags: postgresql, search, full-text-search, escaping

Which characters must be avoided to make sure *PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error in tsquery* will not occur?
The documentation does not say anything about how to escape the search string: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-textsearch.html

Comment: so, where is the quer?

Comment: There are lots of queries. In fact they are secret and I need no more than an answer to my question: How to properly escape the query string?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use quotes around your terms if you want them as phrases/verbatim or they contain characters used in the syntax:

```
select to_tsquery('"hello there" | hi');
```

Bear in mind that you shouldn't really have crazy characters in your terms, since they are not going to match anything in the tsvector.

The (non-token) characters recognized by the tsquery parser are: `\0` (null), `(`, `)`,   (whitespace), `|`, `&`, `:`, `*` and `!`. But how you tokenize your query should be based on how you have setup your dictionary. There are a great many other characters that you will likely not want in your query, not because they will cause a syntax error but because it means you are not tokenizing your query correctly.

Use the `plainto_tsquery` version if it's a simple `AND` query and you don't want to deal with creating the query manually.

Comment: Please define "crazy characters", then my question is answered :-)

Comment: (my primary goal is to avoid any occurence of PSQLException just because somebody entered crazy characters)

Comment: Any character that does not appear in your dictionary. For an english dictionary I'd say: `[^A-Za-z0-9] == crazy`.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe there is a list of characters to avoid (if the search term is outside double quotes)? So that I can remove no more than the problematic characters? For URL encoding I know exactly which characters to avoid, they are on page 12 of RFC 3986: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-12  Where can I find such a definition for tsquery?

Comment: Try [the source](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/tsquery_8c.html#a7dedd4646a8bc9adb2a12b72b0987fa7) ... I've added the chars I could see

Comment: You may also want to handle backslash and comma and single-quote, which have special meanings.

Comment: What am I missing here? `select to_tsquery('"hello there" | hi');` results in `ERROR:  syntax error in tsquery`. Was this an example of what *doesn't* work?