# How to escape underscores in while preparing tsquery for PostgreSQL full text search?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have below [`plainto_tsquery`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html) query as part of [full text searching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html) on a PostgreSQL table.

```
SELECT plainto_tsquery('english', 'flat discount on flight_tickets');
```

This query will return `'flat' & 'discount' & 'flight' & 'ticket'`

Is there any way to make it to return `'flat' & 'discount' & 'flight_ticket'`

Just to avoid closing ticket by marking as duplicate, I have checked below stackoverflow questions

- [Escaping special characters in to_tsquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103880/escaping-special-characters-in-to-tsquery)
- [PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error in tsquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020164/psqlexception-error-syntax-error-in-tsquery/16020565#16020565)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping special characters in to\_tsquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103880/escaping-special-characters-in-to-tsquery)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, No. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020164/psqlexception-error-syntax-error-in-tsquery/16020565#16020565 aslo didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could "pre-process" the text and the queries to replace `_` with a different character like `/`.

```
CREATE INDEX ON texts USING gin (to_tsvector('english', replace(doc, '_', '/')));

SELECT * FROM texts
WHERE to_tsvector('english', replace(doc, '_', '/'))
      @@ plainto_tsquery('english', replace('flat discount on flight_tickets', '_', '/'));
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit on the indexing part, especially that `doc`. My current query is of the form `SELECT * FROM promotions_table WHERE to_tsvector(promotions_table::text) @@ plainto_tsquery('flat discount on flight_tickets')); ` which returns some records and `SELECT * FROM promotions_table WHERE to_tsvector(promotions_table::text) @@ plainto_tsquery( replace('flat discount on flight_tickets', '_', '/'));` is returning empty set

Comment: Of course you also have to use `replace` in the argument to `to_tsvector`, like I wrote in my answer.